# FacebookCore framework AppEventBuiltin (ambiguous use init)

Tags: swift, xcode

I have updated my pods and framework but after that when I try to compile, xcode shows this errors in `AppEventBuiltin` swift (Ambiguous use init)

```
maxRatingValue.onSome({ parameters[.maxRatingValue] = NSNumber(value: UInt64($0)) })

itemCount.onSome({ parameters[.itemCount] = NSNumber(value: UInt64($0)) })
```

[image]

It's for this:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/uint64

[image]

How can I modify these lines for eliminate the errors?

Answer (score 0):

The error happened becouse of Swift 4 updation. If you are using swift 3, replace with the following code:

```
maxRatingValue.onSome({ parameters[.maxRatingValue] = NSNumber(value: $0.toUIntMax()) })

itemCount.onSome({ parameters[.itemCount] = NSNumber(value: $0.toUIntMax()) })
```

Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: Even if it solves the issue, but this code again gets overwritten when we again do pod-install, as we are making change in the pod-framework itself. So whats the permanent solution ?